# Fluent nHibernate Database Connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

In my application i m using fluent nhibernate with MVC 3. i have separate business layer , DAL , and repository layer, now i have to ask where to create the database connection , weather in the DAL or in the MVC (user interface layer)

Note: i want to define the connection string in web.config file.

Does anyone know ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something like this inside my MVC project:-

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="db" 
      connectionString="Server=.;Database=NHCookbook;Trusted_Connection=SSPI;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then in the mvc project I build my session factory like:-

```
  var nhConfig = Fluently
    .Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("db"))
    )
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AMODELCLASS>()
    )
    .BuildConfiguration();

   sessionFactory = nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Yes, I then personally then use `IOC` to pass the session factory to my repository/DAO layer. But as Tomas points out this is optional and could actually be used inside your DAL

Comment: i m getting this error "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory."

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: i m using 3.1 version of nHibernate

Comment: This code was lifted from a demo project I have using 3.1, something else is causing the error. The code is correct

Answer (score 1):

Since the application *running* your code will be the ASP.NET MVC project, the configuration settings in Web.config will be available in any class library. Thus, you should be able to use the configuration code Rippo suggested in any project (however, it won't be reusable from other applications if they don't define a connection string with the same key).

I suggest you let the configuration code for NHIbernate reside in the DAL project, along with other NHibernate related things.

Comment: yeah i m doing the same you suggested. Thanks

Comment: The code Rippo mentioned in his post , is giving exception "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. " any idea what this exception ?